# How can I make OkHttp calls synchronous/blocking?

Tags: java, okhttp

OkHttp is usually asynchronous. A regular call looks like this:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        } else {
            // do something wih the result
        }
    }
}
```

When the message arrives, just do something with it. But I want to use it as a blocking getter. Something like:

```
public void exampleMethod() {
   MyDTO myDto = makeOkHttpCall.getData();
   // do something with myDto Entity
}
```

But all I can find is that I could add code into `onResponse()`. But that is still asynchronous. Any ideas how to change that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `enqueue` you can use `execute` to execute a request synchronously.

See example from the OkHttp documentation:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

(OkHttp documentation: https://square.github.io/okhttp)

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the **OkHttp recipes** on their website.

You will find for example :

- [Synchronous Get (.kt, .java)¶](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#synchronous-get-kt-java)
- [Asynchronous Get (.kt, .java)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java)

The example for *Synchronous Get* in Java being :

```java
  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

      Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
      for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
      }

      System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
  }
```